# Algebraic solutions of polynomial ODEs

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, dg.differential-geometry, gn.general-topology, polynomials, differential-equations

Given a polynomial ODE in $n$-dimensions of maximal degree $d$
$$ 
    \dot{x}_j=f_j(x)=\sum_{i_{1},\dots,i_{n}=1}^{d}a_{i_{1},\dots,i_{n}}^{j}x_{1}^{i_{1}}\dots x_{n}^{i_{n}} \quad \forall j=1,...,n
  $$
we define an algebraic solution as an any curve $\gamma: [t_0,t_1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ solving the ODE and fulfilling
$$
G(\gamma(t))=\sum_{i_{1},\dots,i_{n}=1}^{d'}b_{i_{1},\dots,i_{n}}{\gamma_1(t)}^{i_{1}}\dots {\gamma_n(t)}^{i_{n}}=0 \quad \forall t \in [t_0,t_1]
$$
for some real coefficients $b_{i_1,...,i_n}$.

I am interested in the following set of questions as well as hints to the literature (or partial results in lower dimensions):

1. Is there an algorithm to generally determine whether a polynomial DS has an algebraic solution?
2. Is there a bound on how many algebraic solutions a polynomial ODE can have depending on $n,d$? (I know that some polynomial ODEs like $\dot{x}=-y, \dot{y}=x$ have infinitely many algebraic solutions, but if there are only finite ones, can we bound them.)
3. Can we write those polynomial ODEs in a general form? (I know for $n=2$, two algebraic curves $f,g$ and an antisymmetric matrix $S$, $F=S \nabla (gf)$ has $f,g$ as invariant algebraic curve. But I am not sure if this is the general form.)
4. How many polynomial ODEs generally allow for algebraic solutions? (E.g. identifying the polynomial vector fields with their coefficients which form the set $\mathbb{R}^{n \cdot \binom{n+d}{n}}$. Are the coefficients which allow an algebraic solution dense in $\mathbb{R}^{n \cdot \binom{n+d}{n}}$ or some open subset.)

Answer (score 1):

The literature on the sbject is enormous but most of the known results are limited to small dimensions.
The state of the art is explained in this paper:

MR1914932
Lins Neto, Alcides
Some examples for the Poincaré and Painlevé problems.
Ann. Sci. École Norm. Sup. (4) 35 (2002), no. 2, 231–266.

For the later work, see also references on this paper in Mathscinet. The key words are "Poincare problem", "Darboux integrability", "Algebraic integrability".